# Knockout JS: foreach that increments by 2

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In Knockout JS, is it possible to do a `foreach` that increments by 2? Something similar to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

The reason I'd like to do this is because the data that I need to loop through is an array rather than an object. Example:

```
viewModel = function () {
    this.facets = ["Sample", 100, "Sample 2", 200];
}
```

But the data needs to be displayed like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: facets"> <!-- Can this foreach be incremented by 2? -->
    <li>$data[$index]: $data[$index + 1]</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `knockout` here? what are you asking?

Comment: Your example loop will do precisely that. Where is the problem?

Comment: It is always a good idea to keep the template logic free. You should better prepare a navigable data structure beforehand and keep the templates free from such implementation details.

Comment: This is a simplified example. This data is actually coming back from an `$.ajax` call, and I have no control over how the data is formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a custom binding handler for this but I would rather keep the templates free from such ugly details.

I would recommend writing a [`ko.computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
function Model() {
    this.data = ko.observableArray(["Sample", 100, "Sample 2", 200])
    this.items = ko.computed(function() {
        var value = [];
        var data = this.data();
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=2) {
            value.push({ key: data[i], value: data[i+1]);
        }
        return value;
    }, this);
}

var model = new Model();
```

Now you can iterate over the `items` in your template and access `key` and `value`. Updating the original `data` array will automatically rebuild the `items` computed observable.

The template code would look like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><span data-bind="text: key"></span>: <span data-bind="text: value"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

My Repeat binding (https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) allows you to specify a `step` option.

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="repeat: {foreach: facets, step: 2}"
        data-repeat-bind="text: facets[$index] + ': ' + facets[$index+1]">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    var sample = array[i];
    var number = array[i+1];
    var display = "<li>" + sample + ": " + number + "</li>" // display this
}
```

Looks like you already have it, though, so I'm not sure what the issue is...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to create the structure you need to bind to:

```
 self.arrayFunc = function() {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i += 2) {
        result.push({first: array[i], second: [i + 1]};
    }

};
```